# File not found for php files

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I have wordpress running behind nginx reverse proxy.

Home etc works fine but when user goes to url with .php ending, I'm getting 404 `File not found.` error.

Here is related nginx configuration:

```
        location /en/us/ {
                proxy_pass https://10.0.10.11/en/us/;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean "related"? Are there other `location` blocks in this configuration file?

Comment: For this path, no there is not. wordpress home works fine under /en/us/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there was another rule which were overriding all php files and returning 404. If you are using bitnami nginx, edit following file;

`sudo vim /opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf`

and comment out

`#include "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/phpfastcgi.conf";`

which is

```
location ~ "\.php$" {
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    if (!-f $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        return 404;
    }

    include /etc/nginx/conf/phpfastcgiparam.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php7/php-fpm.sock;
}
```